# Not sure how to return endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a Node/Express API where I am not sure how to return the results of a $group.

My code:

```
router.route('/viewed_card/:invite_id')
    .get(function(req, res){
     Profile.aggregate([
            {$unwind:'$contacts'},
            {$unwind:'$contacts.shared'},
            {$match:{'contacts.shared.invite_id':req.params.invite_id}},
            {$group:{
                _id:null,
                first_name:{$first:'$contacts.first_name'},
                last_name:{$first:'$contacts.last_name'}
            }}
        ])

    })
```

How do I return the results?

I tried doing a "return" just before the "Profile.aggregate" function.

I though maybe something like this:

```
router.route('/viewed_card/:invite_id')
    .get(function(req, res){
     Profile.aggregate([
            {$unwind:'$contacts'},
            {$unwind:'$contacts.shared'},
            {$match:{'contacts.shared.invite_id':req.params.invite_id}},
            {$group:{
                _id:null,
                first_name:{$first:'$contacts.first_name'},
                last_name:{$first:'$contacts.last_name'}
            }}
        ], function(err, result){
            return result;
        }

    })
```

But nothing...

Comment: In the callback, you should write `res.send(result)`

Comment: If your runtime supports it you can also use async await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong the aggregation returns promise, you can try this way

```
var profile=Profile.aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$contacts'},
    {$unwind:'$contacts.shared'},
    {$match:{'contacts.shared.invite_id':req.params.invite_id}},
    {$group:{
        _id:null,
        first_name:{$first:'$contacts.first_name'},
        last_name:{$first:'$contacts.last_name'}
    }}
]);

profile.then((data) => {
    res.status(200).jsonp({
        data
    });
})
.catch(err => {
    res.status(422).jsonp({errors: err});
});
```

Or you can use something like `cursor`

```
Profile.aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$contacts'},
    {$unwind:'$contacts.shared'},
    {$match:{'contacts.shared.invite_id':req.params.invite_id}},
    {$group:{
        _id:null,
        first_name:{$first:'$contacts.first_name'},
        last_name:{$first:'$contacts.last_name'}
    }}
]).toArray(function(err, results) {
    if(!err) res.status(200).jsonp(ageNodes);
    else res.status(422).jsonp(err);
});
```

Comment: abdulbarik, Thanks for your help. I've been getting to know the aggregate framework better as a result. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Send the data you care about back in the response `res` object.

You are in `function(req, res) {}`, where you have a request `req` object and a response `res` object. You're extracting information from `req` to get the first and last name. Use `res` to send the result back.